# Database scalability concerns

Tags: mysql, database

I'm building a fairly large SaaS system that will be used by several businesses.

Right now, there is a single MySQL database that holds all the data, but as it seems there may quite a lot of data added monthly (I would say at least 5-10k entries per connected business, and we may have 100-200 businesses connected), I am starting to fear that the DB will grow very rapidly and maybe the queries may be slow due to the amount of data available.

The system is hosted on AWS, thus scalable.

Some questions:

1) is the fear of slowdown a valid one?

2) am I better off splitting into multiple databases, one for each business?

3) if you recommend multiple, please note that there will be shared member that may be able to access data from several of the businesses. How would I handle that?

Regards,

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have 100 businesses each reporting 5k entities, you're looking at growth of 5,000,000 records per month.

Avoid thinking of that number as big or small, at least by itself. You actually have to step back and think about what kind of data you'll be storing, what kind of queries you'll be running, how much memory you can afford to dedicate to MySQL, and what kind of response time is acceptable. If this is SaaS, you'll want to keep response time low... maybe you data are very basic (a small handful of columns) and people want to ask questions like "How many entities has each business had, on average, over the past year." With good indices, that would be a very doable query. With good indices as something like materialized views (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) or summary tables, it may not be a problem at all. Maybe you can add caching into the equation too. It all just really depends.

In answer to your question, though, is fear of a slowdown valid? Well, yes and no. Is it possible? Very much yes. Should you be afraid of it? No. You should manage your data in a way that it's not likely to happen.

Which brings us to parts 2-3 of your question: are you better of splitting your data into multiple databases and how would you handle access?

Well, the answer is again "it depends." But given that you are asking the question that you are, I suspect database replication and ensuring consistency across multiple DBs is probably not something you want to chew off, at least not right now.

Hence, you have several options. One, think about what questions you'll need to ask and whether or not they can be meaningfully pre-summarized. Think along the lines of OLAP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) even if not specifically OLAP. Maybe you can summarize the data with some sort of a process and store it in much smaller tables... in which case good indices should keep you out of trouble.

Maybe you need to fall back to something Hadoop-based, like Storm or Impala or Spark. Elastic search might come in handy too, depending, or Redis/memcache.

It really all depends on (a) what data you will be storing (b) what queries you need to execute against it and (c) what technologies you are most comfortable and proficient using. Not all big data problem are equal. It's not difficult to imagine cases in which 500 million records is a smaller "big data" problem than one that involves 50 million records. It really depends on what data you're dealing with and what you need to do with it.

So.... suffice it to say there is no one right answer to this question. That's why people in big data careers have their hands so full all the time. There's a lot you have to think about, and very few black-and-white, simple answers.